# Solving $5^{x-2} = 3^{3x+2}$ without log

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have an equation.
$$5^{x-2} = 3^{3x+2}$$
I have to solve for $x$.

I know I can use log to solve this equation.But I wanted to know what is wrong with my other method.

$$\begin{align}
 5^{x-2} &= 3^{3x+2} \tag1\\[4pt]
\frac{5^x}{5^2} &= 3^{3x} \times 3^2 \tag2\\[4pt]
\frac{5^x}{3^{3x}} &= 5^2 \times 3^2 \tag3
\end{align}$$

As $3^{3x}$ will never be zero, I can safely divide by it.

$$ 5^x \times 3^{-3x} = 5^2 \times 3^2 \tag4$$

Now clearly, $x$ has to be equal to $2$ to match the exponent of $5$, but that solves the equality. $\square$

Kindly let me know where I commit the mistake.

Comment: Obviously there is no real need to “match the exponent of $5$”. This reasoning is invalid.

Comment: This would be sort of valid reasoning on the integers where you have prime factorization, but that's not what's going on here.

Comment: Notice that if you look at the exponent of 3 instead, you get the equation $-3x = 2$ which has a completely different solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning would be on the right track if the bases were related to each other exponentially (i.e. $3$ and $9$) because you could represent the equations to get the same base. However, life isn't always that nice. Instead of getting several million-dollar budget movies, life gives you 80 episodes of Skibidi Toilet. You have to use logarithms here if you want a nice-ish answer.

---

$$5^{x-2}=3^{3x+2}$$
$$e^{\ln(5^{x-2})}=e^{\ln(3^{3x+2})}$$

There is a useful logarithm property that allows us to move the exponent to the front, as follows.

$$e^{(x-2)\ln(5)}=e^{(3x+2)\ln(3)}$$
$$(x-2)\ln(5)=(3x+2)\ln(3)$$
$$x\ln(5)-2\ln(5)=3\ln(3)x+2\ln(3)$$

Doing the reverse of the aforementioned property means we can turn terms like $3\ln(3)$ to $\ln(3^3)$. In general, $a\ln(b)=\ln(b^a)$ and vice versa. Applying this where helpful gives

$$x\ln(5)-2\ln(5)=\ln(3^3)x+2\ln(3)$$
$$x\ln(5)-x\ln(27)=2\ln(3)+2\ln(5)$$
$$x\cdot [\ln(5)-\ln(27)]=2\cdot[\ln(3)+\ln(5)]$$

Another property of logarithms is that $\ln(x)+\ln(y)=\ln(xy)$ and the inverse is $\ln(x)-\ln(y)=\ln(\frac{x}{y})$. We'll apply those to get

$$x\cdot [\ln(\frac{5}{27})]=2\cdot [\ln(15)]$$
$$\fbox{
    \( 
x=\frac{2\ln(15)}{\ln(\frac{5}{27})}\)
}$$

Do what you want with this, because there are many other ways you could represent this fraction using the aforementioned logarithm properties.